# Blocking Window Distance Estimation in sCMOS Sensor setup

Tags: distance, sensor

I am trying to establish an appropriate distance between a spectrograph output window and a CMOS sensor.

The spectrograph creates a focussed image on the CMOS sensor, but I need to block out some of the pixels in the border. Therefore, I need to determine at what distance the blocking window needs to be placed.

I hope the image will illustrate my problem at best.

[image: Problem Illustration]

Comment: The answer is "as close as possible", but in order to answer this we need more information. Specifically, what is the depth of focus of the setup focusing light onto the sensor (this relates to the size of the lens and the focal length), and what level of blur on the outer edges can you tolerate? Without that, it is meaningless to give you an answer. Also - since X-by-Y are unknown dimensions of the window - do you know the size of the border you are trying to eliminate?

Comment: @Floris I am trying to "see" 2560 (spatial pixels) and 500th-1600th (spectral pixels). So, I am thinking the horizontal window dimensions would remain the same (at 16.64 mm), but the vertical dimension is unknown. For example, vertical dimension would be 7.15 mm if the window is placed EXACTLY on the sensor. I am trying to establish how far to place the window. I can place the window anywhere between 5mm to 10mm from the sCMOS sensor.

Comment: It really depends on the position and size of the lens that creates the "focused image". I recommend you do this experimentally.